# bind first property value of an array of object into chart.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, chart.js

I have an array of object and this is how I assigned values into it.

```
  $("#gridview").click(function () {
            $("table tbody th").each(function () {
                var k = $(this).text().trim();
                keys.push(k);
            });
            $("table tbody tr").each(function (i, el) {
                var row = {}
                $.each(keys, function (k, v) {
                    row[v] = $("td:eq(" + k + ")", el).text().trim();
                });
                myData.push(row);
            });
            myData.shift()
            myData.length = 10

            console.log(myData);
        });
```

This is how my array of object looks like in inspect element - console

[image]

how can I get the values of **Region** and bind it to the **labels** below:

```
 new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
            type: 'horizontalBar',
            data: {
                labels: [I want to display all the region here],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Android",
                    type: "horizontalBar",
                    stack: "Base",
                    backgroundColor: "#eece01",
                    data: ["I want to display ios user here"],
                }, {
                    label: "ios",
                    type: "horizontalBar",
                    stack: "Base",
                    backgroundColor: "#87d84d",
                    data: ["I want to display android user here"]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        //stacked: true,
                        stacked: true,
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            maxRotation: 0,
                            minRotation: 0
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                    }]
                },
            }
        });
```

**FYI** I have tried **myData[Region]** but its not working

Guys, I have searched the solutions whole day, seems cant found, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `labels` using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on `myData` array like:

```
data: {
   labels: myData.map(d => d.Region),
   ....
},
```

**EDIT:**

You can create a new function and add all chart init code into it like:

```
function CreateChart() {
   new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      data: {
         labels: myData.map(d => d.Region),
         ... you code here
      },
      ...
   });
}

CreateChart();
```

and then on `gridview` click, again call this `CreateChart` function in the end like:

```
$("#gridview").click(function() {
   // all your code logic here
   console.log(myData);
   CreateChart();
});
```

Comment: btw can you help me with one more issue? do you have any idea how to remove the space between the `Android User` ? Please refer back to the image above

Comment: Please create a separate question for that so that we can focus on one specific issue at a time. And also that would help other users to help you provide detailed answers for a specific issue.